# What was Summer doing with her tongue, and why did it surprise Seth?

Tags: the-oc

In the series finale of *The O.C.*, a flashforward sequence shows

> Seth and Summer getting married.

As Summer

> is walking down the aisle,

she pokes her tongue out at Seth. For a moment he looks surprised or shocked, then moments later stops, as if he remembered some old in-joke between them, rendering the conventional meaning of the tongue-poke to be moot.

What does this any of this signify? I didn't understand either the supposed meaning of the tongue-poke or Seth's eventual realisation of its *true* meaning in context.

Comment: I had always assumed that it was just Summer being Summer.  She was just acting silly at a time that was supposed to be "serious." I think it just showed the playfulness of their relationship.

Comment: @followthemeow: Perhaps so, but his reaction seemed to indicate something more.

Answer (score 1):

So in googling this I just came across what appears to actually be a scholarly book on the series called ["The O.C.: A Critical Understanding" by Lori Bindig and Andrea M. Bergstrom](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vn8JDadlsQsC&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=summer+sticks+her+tongue+out+at+seth&source=bl&ots=uNC8ys756e&sig=CK1x0oH2qTMRSQXcBirkEpw9ZmU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR9cTljMvSAhWHxYMKHW5QDowQ6AEIQTAJ#v=onepage&q=summer%20sticks%20her%20tongue%20out%20at%20seth&f=false), and the paragraph on it doesn't really answer the question (but in SO parlance I believe it contributes something here) but it addresses it. That paragraph actually cites another book that I don't have access to ATM:

> Though Summer's act of sticking her tongue out could be interpreted as
>   a rebellious moment, mocking the traditional gender roles associated
>   with marriage, or viewed as a sign of her former frivolous ways, it is
>   almost inconsequential. Rather, Summer's marriage to Seth resembles a
>   myriad of media texts that depic a women's (sic) greatest achievement
>   as getting married. Thus as Summer's storyline ends, it reflects the
>   hegemonic notion that "no emotional, professional, or political
>   accomplishment can possibly compare with the twin vocations of beauty and marriage" (Zeisler, 2008, p.126)

The Zeisler reference is probably "Feminism and Pop Culture" by Andi Zeisler

Comment: Am I dreaming?!